# Error pasando tabla HTML a Excel con xlsx.full.min.js

Tags: javascript, excel

Estoy pasando una tabla HTML a Excel y lo hace completamente, pero algunos textos los cambia por fechas.
Ejemplo: el texto "REINT SOB CC.08-1-0007  " lo cambia por "31/07/2007"
Que estará pasando?
Gracias de antemano por la ayuda que puedan prestarme.
Saludos

nota: la tabla pasa toda sin errores pero cambia algunos textos por fechas

```
<html>
<head>
<title>mayorAnaliticoExcel</title></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='./js/aExcel-xlsx.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='./js/xlsx.full.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Por favor espere....</h1><br>
<table id="mayorAnaliticoExcel"  style="display: none" summary="Code page support in different versions of MS Windows.">
<tr><th>Demo, C.A.</th><th></th><th>Mayor Analitico al: 022023</th ></tr><th>Cuenta</th><th>Descripcion</th></colgroup></tr><tr><th>detalle del asiento</th><th>nro.comprobante</th><th>fecha</th><th>Saldo Anterior</th><th>Debe</th><th>Haber</th><th>Saldo Actual</th><tr>
<tr><td>1-1-02-01-001</td><td>Banco Tal   </td></tr>
<tr><td> REINT SOB CC.08-1-0007  </td><td>0210002-001</td><td> 23-02-2023</td><td></td><td></td><td>          1000.00 </td></tr>
<tr><td> ITF:3 RIF:V011111119</td><td>0210002-002</td><td> 23-02-2023</td><td></td><td></td><td>            20.00 </td></tr>
<tr><td> NDB:3 RIF:V011111119</td><td>0210002-005</td><td> 23-02-2023</td><td></td><td></td><td>            10.00 </td></tr>
<tr><td> ITF:3 RIF:V011111119</td><td>0210002-006</td><td> 23-02-2023</td><td></td><td></td><td>             0.20 </td></tr>
<tr><td> NCR:4 RIF:V011111119</td><td>0210002-008</td><td> 23-02-2023</td><td></td><td>          1000.00 </td></tr>
<tr><td> DEP:1 RIF:V011111119</td><td>0210002-009</td><td> 23-02-2023</td><td></td><td>          1000.00 </td></tr>
<tr><td> CHE:2 RIF:V011111119</td><td>0210002-010</td><td> 23-02-2023</td><td></td><td></td><td>          1000.00 </td></tr>
<h1 style='color:blue'>Hoja de Excel del "Mayor Analitico del 02-2023 terminada !!!</h1><br><br>
<input type="button" onclick="ExportExcel('xlsx','','','mayorAnaliticoExcel','MayorAnalitico','Hoja1')" value="Descargar Hoja de Excel" style='font-size:19px;color:green'> 
 <input type="button" value="Salir" onClick="history.back(-1)" style='font-size:19px;color:red'>
</body>
</html>
```

la funcion ExportExcel es la siguiente:

```
function ExportExcel(type, fn, dl, idNombre, nombreLibro, Hoja) {
   //console.log("type:"+type,"idNombre:"+idNombre,"nombreHoja:"+nombreLibro,"Hoja:"+Hoja);
         var elt = document.getElementById(idNombre);
         var nombreLibro = nombreLibro+"."
         var wb = XLSX.utils.table_to_book(elt, {sheet: Hoja});
         return dl ?
            XLSX.write(wb, {bookType:type, bookSST:true, type: 'base64'}) :
            XLSX.writeFile(wb, fn || ( nombreLibro + (type || 'xlsx')));
}
```

Comment: Hola Edgar, bienvenido, para poder ayudarte, necesitamos tu código, edita tu pregunta y agregalo en formato texto (solo la parte involucrada en tu problema, y de ser posible que se pueda ejecutar), y si recibes errores, indica cuales son.  

mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.

aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!.

Answer (score 0):

Amigos, instale la version 0.19.2 de xlsx.full.min.js y ya fue corregido.
https://cdn.sheetjs.com/xlsx-0.19.2/package/dist/xlsx.full.min.js
Gracias de todos modos
Saludos